# Naming class instances in a "for" loop (cocoa)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, initialization

I would like to instantiate some custom objects in a for loop retrieving them from an array. I also would like to give the pointer the name of an array's value. (Example)

personArray in generalArray value: 0=name , 1=address, 2=mobile…

Object: Person (with the instante variables of the personArray)

```
////////

for (NSArray*person in generalArray){

NSString*name=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[person ObjectAtIndex:0];
NSString*address=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[person ObjectAtIndex:1];
…

//Now I want to instantiate objects "person" with "name, address…" variables. I also tried to name pointers with the "name" NSString.

}
```

Are there any solutions?

Comment: I can not understand your question. Please give a better description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set the name of a variable, pointer or otherwise, to the value of another variable. So in your case you are looking to set the name of a pointer to be the value of the name/address NSString. That is just something that is not possible to do.

To instantiate a 'Person' object from the for loop:

```
for (NSArray*person in generalArray){

NSString*name=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[person ObjectAtIndex:0];
NSString*address=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[person ObjectAtIndex:1];
…

PersonObject *person = [[PersonObject alloc] init];

// Assuming your person object has a name and address property
person.name = name;
person.address = address;


// You should also add the newly created person object to a data collection in order for
// it to be saved. If you don't do that then each iteration will create a new person
// object, but it will not be saved anywhere, which means it's a pointless operation. 
}
```

This is creating a new person object with each iteration of the for loop. You are now taking the name and address information from the person array and placing it into the newly created person object.

Comment: ok, and so how can I instantiate my objects in the loop?

Comment: You can, of course, with "graduate level" Objective-C, add new setters and getters to a class to effectively add new properties, and you can also play games with valueForUndefinedKey, et al.  But that's well above the OP's pay grade, I suspect.